# Get Property value from dbset core 2.1

Tags: entity-framework-core

How can i run the following code dynamically:

```
_context.TableName.First().Value;
```

I try this:

```
_context.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name == "PropertyName").First().GetValue(_context, null)
```

But i cant call the First() Method.

Comment: This is a really peculiar thing to do. Let's say you get it working, what will you do with the result?

Comment: Isn't it just `_context.Property<string>("PropertyName").Value;`?